# Can I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in a dll/xll

Tags: c#, dll, xll, microsoft.office.interop.excel

I am writing a ConsoleApp in C# to open and make some modifications to an Excel workbook, and I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. It works quite well, but my goal is to write a dll/xll to do the job with a call from an excel macro.
Can that be done, and if yes, how can I get an Excel.Workbook handle attached to the calling Excel process ?

I am rather new to this, so forgive me if I ask silly questions :-)

Comment: If you're talking about Excel VSTO AddIn, then yes, you can.

Comment: No, I am talking about Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Comment: So, you're wrong. The only way to `do the job with a call from an excel macro` is to create Excel AddIn. You can expose method(s) to Excel VBA, then you can use it thfough the VBA code. See: [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)

Comment: I'd check out [ExcelDna](https://excel-dna.net/) - it's pretty much the last word in C#/Excel interop!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but writing an xll is an extremely complex process compared to calling `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` from a console app.

To create an xll you need to implement all the relevant functions shown in the [XLL SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/welcome-to-the-excel-software-development-kit). After that, it is simple enough to get a pointer to the `Excel.Application` interface.